# Service host with 4 children eats up to 20% of CPU; what does it doing?

Tags: windows, cpu-usage, high-cpu-usage

I found, that Service host is eating too many CPU resources:

[image]

How to know, what does it doing?

`procexp64.exe` shows even less information (no child process list).

Shutting down this process causes no apparent damage.

Comment: You could try stopping the services one-by-one whilst monitoring CPU usage in order to work out which is the culprit. This should make it easier to find the root cause.

Comment: That's because they are not child processes. They are services running within the parent process.

Answer (score 1):

Capture a [xperf trace](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-42-WPT-CPU-Analysis) of the CPU usage:

> xperf -on latency -stackwalk profile -buffersize 2048 -MaxFile 2048
>   -FileMode Circular && timeout -1 && xperf -d C:\HighCPUUsage.etl

and when you open it in WPA and expand the stack, you probably see that the UPNP service **waits** (highlighted in red).

[image]

So stop that service to fix the issue.