# PC lagging, tools report conflicting info

Tags: windows, windows-10, cpu, cpu-usage, intel-core-i5

My computer UI was laggy this morning so I open up Task Manager; I find that across two tabs one shows 100% CPU utilization but the other tab shows 85-97% Idle.  I've never seen this computer peg all four cores like this, and it has been this way since rebooting this morning.

Usually I'd look at the "Details" section for offending processes but it shows mostly idle over the 5 hours of uptime.

Any hints on where I can start to troubleshoot this?

[image: 99% Idle]

[image: 100% Active]

**UPDATE**
Computer stayed in this state all night. Rebooted this morning and after the system settled I had PerfMon ad TaskMan showing 100% CPU while Process Explorer showed mostly idle.  I walked away for a couple of hours, PerfMon's CPU graph is starting to show some quiet periods but TaskMan continues to show 100% CPU while PE shows mostly nothing.

Any thoughts on troubleshooting this?  PC borders on unusable, if I cannot fix it then I have to tear it down and start from scratch (a task I do not relish).

[image: Screen shot Process Explorer, Task Manager, Resource Monitor (perfmon), and Open Hardware Monitor]

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/990120/174557

Comment: again, provide the xperf trace, not the useless pictures

Comment: Done.  What am I looking for?  Report shows system mostly idle.

Comment: analyze it like shown here https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-42-WPT-CPU-Analysis or zip and share the file so that I can look at it